# Диалог запроса разрешений

Tags: android, интерфейс

Доброго всем дня!
Подскажите, кто знает, вот такой диаог

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

кто рисует? Это системный (скажем, в 6м андроиде такой стал) или это какая-то библиотечка?

Имею ввиду что он не такой как обычный:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а разве, как раз таки, первый не является обычным(стандартным) для android, а второй(тот что ниже) копией iOS'ного(или же оригинал)

Comment: второй скриншот не с Android. Он не является *обычным* ни на грамм.

Comment: Действительно, со вторым лопухнулся. Заказчик голову заморочил совсем. Вот увидел что другое приложение вот такие запросы рисует, вот надо чтоб тоже также. А мое, редиска, не рисует такие запросы, а только обычные черные при установке. Я так, вот "полистал литературу" - этот первый сркин - это запрос runtime permissions на 6ке? А так как мой софт был под 4ку, соотвественно и нет таких диалогов. Правильно понимаю?

Comment: Второй диалог - стандартный iOSный. Первый - 6й и выше андроид запрос в рантайме

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый - это системный.

Для удобства запроса прав, можно использовать библиотеку [Dexter](http://joerichard.net/android/android-runtime-permissions-and-how-dexter-library-makes-life-easy/)

```
 Dexter.checkPermission(
    new CompositePermissionListener(
        new PermissionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                // права были даны
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                // прав нет
            }

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, final PermissionToken token) {
                token.continuePermissionRequest();
            }
        },
        /* Отображаем снэкбар с кнопкой и текстом */
        SnackbarOnDeniedPermissionListener.Builder
                .with((ViewGroup) mActivity.findViewById(com.app.R.id.RootView), "Дайте права на ..., они нужны будут для ...")
                .withOpenSettingsButton("Название кнопки")
                .build()),
    Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
```

Comment: Благодарю, разобрался.